# Microsoft tts Mark mobile

Tags: python

Hey guys I'm having a bit of a problem using `pyttsx3`, it was working quite well few days ago but now it's giving issues. I set it's property voice Mark mobile but it sounds like zira every time I run it

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
engine.setProperty('voice', 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\TTS_MS_EN_-US_DAVID_11.0')

engine.say('Hello sir')
engine.runAndWait()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is close, but you need to add `voices = engine.getProperty('voices')` to get the options of voices:

```
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()

voices = engine.getProperty('voices') # Get the options of voices

engine.setProperty('voice',voices[1].id) # Instead of the path use the variable defined above

engine.say('Hello sir')

engine.runAndWait()
```